# Setting up an universal application in ios

Tags: ios, universal

I have created an universal application which runs fine on my ipad . But the image sizing for the iphone isnt perfect . I have tried all the view modes .Can anyone help with this issue .
I have added all the images with all the different resolutions .

Comment: for universal app you have two storyboards one for iPhone Devices and one For iPad devices. do you have this both..?

Comment: Have you supplied images for both iPad and iPhone and the different resolutions as well so your normal ones, `@2x` ones and `@3x` ones?

Comment: image.png image@2x.png image-568h@2x.png

Comment: Now its running fine for 4inch iphone bt 320 480 image is not displayed fully .  if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
      
        if(result.height == 568)
        {
             _myimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"darkback-568h.png"];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"hi");
            _myimage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"darkback.png"];
        }

Answer (score 0):

Create two different storyboard/xib for iPhone and i Pad.

You have to check condition for iPhone and i Pad.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
//for i Pad.
}
else

{
//for iPhone.
}
```

Comment: Yes am using two storyboards for iphone and ipad seperately .

Answer (score 0):

Check under project - Deployment Info if your iPhone and iPad refers to the correct Main interfaces (for iPhone you should have youre iPhone storyboard and for iPad your iPad storyboard).
You can find Deployment info here [image]